# VS 2013 does not see angular typescript typings

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

Visual Studio cannot resolve interface `ng.IScope` (and others from ng module).

I have added reference to `angular.d.ts` but it doesn't help.

What's interesting a rectangular typings are working fine - even without adding the reference.

I am using `Visual Studio 2013 Update 4` with `TypeScript 1.4`. Anyone can help? I tried everything.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I'm having the same problem and can see that other typings are working ok

Answer (score 2):

> I am using visual studio 2013 update 4 with TypeScript 1.4. Anyone can help? I tried everything :/

Suspect its just an issue of an old version lingering around. Try `where tsc` and make sure you only see `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\`.

> I have added reference to angular.d.ts but it doesn't help. What's interesting a restangular typings are working fine - even without adding the reference.

Make sure you have it added to the visual studio *project*.

Answer (score 0):

Any luck ? 
I have the same problem, however, if you use the older version
    angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped version=0.9.6 
    (Nuget -> Install-Package angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped -Version 0.9.6)
everything works fine and it understands the ng.IScope definition.

I don't see any structural difference between 3.1.3 and 0.9.6, so I don't understand why the older version works.